# What are options of connecting to RMS files on Openvms using BizTalk or SSIS?

Tags: ssis, biztalk, openvms

Are there any interfaces provided by OpenVMS?
ODBC? WebService?
Attunity adapters are ruled out due to Cost.
Any pointers would be useful..
Thanks
paritosh

Answer (score 0):

If there is an oracle db on the VMS then oracle adapter is obviously an option.

If not, then except from costly solutions, you can use the file adepter with samba, or the ftp adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial and open source packages for ODBC and JDBC connections (including connections into RMS files, and packages and tools for connections into databases including Oracle Rdb, Oracle classic, MySQL or otherwise) are available for OpenVMS.  Yes, including Attunity Connect.

For a related discussion of ODBC and JDBC options on OpenVMS, see http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/668

There is also a gSOAP port available for OpenVMS, see http://www.johndapps.com/

I'd suggest specific verification that any ODBC or JDBC package intended for connections into Oracle (and whether Rdb or classic) would (also) operate with RMS files, if that's part of your requirements and that's under consideration here.